# Notepad++ - How can I search (per line) until a certain character (in said line)?

Tags: notepad++

I have several lines which look like

```
\node[ ... Some code here ... { ... some more code
\node[ ... Some code here ... { ... some more code
\node[ ... Some code here ... { ... some more code
```

In each line, I'd like to replace the code from `[` to `{` with my own code.

- `\node` is always at the beginning of each line.
- `{` is *not* at the end of the line.

I've already found (on here) and tried stuff like `^\\node.*\{` or `\\node.*\{`, but both produce the same unsatisfactory result: the whole code until the very last`{` in the document gets marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's completely fine to enable Wrap around. In fact, I suggest you do.

Since the fragment is guaranteed to be at the beginning of the line, you can use a caret (`^`) anchor.

The following works for me:

Find: `^\\node\[[^{]*\{`; Replace with: `\\node[test{`

The `^` anchors to beginning of line. `\\node\[` matches the text `\node[`, after escaping for special characters. `[^{]*` grabs every character except for an open brace. (Note that here, `{` doesn't need to be escaped because it's in a character class.) Then `\{` grabs the open brace itself.

---

**If** `... Some code here ...` **can contain braces:**

Find: `^\\node\[.*\{([^{]*)$`; Replace with: `\\node[test{$1`

The first part is the same. Then, `.*` will match as many characters as possible. `\{` matches an opening brace, then `([^{]*)$` matches and captures all the characters until the end of the line. Since `[^{]` is specified, then it will not match any opening braces, so the previous `\{` must be match the last `{` on the line.

Answer (score 1):

In the Search / Replace dialog, using Find what: **node[.*{** and Replace with: **node[test{** successfully replaces **...Some code here...** with **test** on each line.

You do have to specify the following options:

- Do NOT tick "Wrap around"
- Tick "Regular expression"
- Do NOT tick ". matches newline"
  [image]

Comment: Although a bit belated: didn't work. :/ http://imgur.com/9DcCORg